# Unwanted ≥ showing in Lightbox2

Tags: lightbox2

How can I remove the "≥" link button (and the line it occupies) which appears above my thumbnails when using Lightbox2? I have checked through the CSS which accompanies the js and cannot find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In the lightbox2 CSS sheet the images that attach to those white next link buttons can be found in this block of code. Don't forget to remove it from the states like a:hover. You can always go to other websites for similar png files to change the slider options for nav left and right.

```
.lb-nav a.lb-prev {
width: 34%;
left: 0;
float: left;
background: url(../images/prev.png) left 48% no-repeat;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
-o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
transition: opacity 0.6s;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-prev {
width: 34%;
left: 0;
float: left;
background: url(../images/prev.png) left 48% no-repeat;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
-o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
transition: opacity 0.6s;
}
```